# How to define swagger json schema to validate mandatory of keys in one field based on their types in another field

Tags: swagger, jsonschema

I'm trying to extend the swagger 2.0 json schema (http://json.schemastore.org/swagger-2.0) to validate for my swagger file with specific rules. In the schema, I want to make propertyName of a few **securityDefinitions** objects to be required in property **security**. A sample valid definition looks like this in YAML format: (I use vscode https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-yaml/ to validate yaml against json schemas)

```
securityDefinitions:
  myClientSecret:
    type: apiKey
    x-key-type: client_secret
    name: X-My-Client-Secret
    in: header
  myClientId:
    type: apiKey
    x-key-type: client_Id
    name: X-My-Client-Id
    in: header
security:
  - myClientSecret []
    myClientId []
```

Following validation rules are expected:

1. Property with x-key-type *client_id* is required in **securityDefinitions**
2. Property with x-key-type *client_secret* is required in **securityDefinitions**
3. The propertyName *myClientId* and *myClientSecret* are required array element in **security** because their x-key-type are required in **securityDefinitions**

How to validate this with json schema?

Comment: As an alternative approach, instead of changing the standard JSON Schema use OpenAPI linting tools to verify the presence of your custom required fields.

Comment: Second this. Unless you're very familiar with JSON Schema, you're going to have a REALLY hard time extending the JSON Schema for swagger / OpenAPI before OpenAPI 3.1!

Comment: Actually what I want to achieve is to validate the specific rules (client_id & client_secret must be defined in securityDefinitions and enabled in security) both in VSCode and on server side during deployment. Which tools will you recommend?